# problem with the inactive RAID 5

Tags: raid, mdadm

I have a server running ubuntu server, after a crash, I lost a Disc.
Here is the output:

```
cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5]      [raid4] [raid10]
md0 : active raid1 cciss/c0d0p1[0] cciss/c0d1p1[1] cciss/c0d2p1[2]
  489856 blocks [3/3] [UUU]

 md2 : active raid1 cciss/c0d0p3[0] cciss/c0d1p3[1] cciss/c0d2p3[2]
  138938048 blocks [3/3] [UUU]

 md1 : active raid1 cciss/c0d0p2[0] cciss/c0d1p2[1] cciss/c0d2p2[2]
  3903680 blocks [3/3] [UUU]

md3 : inactive cciss/c0d5p1[2](S) cciss/c0d3p1[0](S) cciss/c0d4p1[1](S) cciss/c0d6p1[3](S)
  573327104 blocks

cat /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
# mdadm.conf
#
# Please refer to mdadm.conf(5) for information about this file.
#

# by default, scan all partitions (/proc/partitions) for MD superblocks.
# alternatively, specify devices to scan, using wildcards if desired.
DEVICE partitions

# auto-create devices with Debian standard permissions
CREATE owner=root group=disk mode=0660 auto=yes

# automatically tag new arrays as belonging to the local system
HOMEHOST <system>

# instruct the monitoring daemon where to send mail alerts
MAILADDR root

# definitions of existing MD arrays
ARRAY /dev/md0 level=raid1 num-devices=3  UUID=e36f9237:d7a2a830:b3dedfb7:5e31bd86
ARRAY /dev/md1 level=raid1 num-devices=3 UUID=f1b3fc22:5cbadae9:c68d4e56:4c57b156
ARRAY /dev/md2 level=raid1 num-devices=3 UUID=58a9609b:3132051a:018fbdf9:bef9dca9
ARRAY /dev/md3 level=raid5 num-devices=5 UUID=459df1f2:70ea10af:40314e29:0652aa8c

# This file was auto-generated on Thu, 07 Aug 2008 03:22:07 +0000
```

Help

Comment: Could you also show us `mdadm --detail /dev/md3`?

Comment: Is this Software RAID using slices from the HP Smart Array controller or Hardware RAID mapped through into userspace? If it's the second won't you need to use the BIOS-level RAID configuration utility to fix the array?

Comment: thank you for your reply, i think that Hardware RAID mapped through into userspace,
 how i can have the confirmation ?because i have not been configured

Comment: output off :~# mdadm --detail /dev/md3
mdadm: md device /dev/md3 does not appear to be active.

Comment: `mdadm --examine /dev/cciss/c0d?p1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excuse me for the late reply, i found the solution by following this procedure

mdadm --stop /dev/md3  then
mdadm --assemble --force /dev/md3